# how to pick the low carbon steel scrap from ms trolley using electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism

I want to pick the low carbon steel scrap using the electromagnet from the ms trolley in which the low carbon steel scrap is present? how to pick the scrap without effecting the ms trolley(95kgs), how to specify the design parameters without making any changes in the design of the trolley.

Comment: What is an "ms trolley?"

Comment: What is “ms”? Medium Size? Multiple Sectioned? What have you considered so far? You should elaborate what you have done so we don’t waste effort repeating work and you reply “considered that, it won’t work because of x or y”. This is not a free design service - you need to show some effort then people may help.

Comment: I did not know Micro Soft made trolleys.

Comment: @Oldfart yes, they are “small” and “hard”... Apparently the Japanese men think micro-soft is not a “manly” name...

Comment: Mild Steel, possibly?

Comment: @HandyHowie we’ve all been working around that, expecting the OP to improve the question....

Comment: Hmm, assuming you want to electromagnetically remove carbon steel from mild steel, you  should probably build the whole trolley around the task rather than trying not to change the trolley.

Comment: Probably "metal scrap'. As an initialization it should be capitalised to MS anyway.

Comment: @transistor yeah that makes sense.  Now we have to figure out what he means by trolley.  I think magnetic metal separation would be better to do on a conveyor belt or as metal pieces fall through the air.  I guess it depends on the mix and particle size.

Comment: is this the ms trolley you refer to? something similar perhaps? http://www.asm-engineers.com/m-s-scrap-trolley-3729870.html

Comment: construct the trolley from wood, aluminium, or some other non-magnetic material.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has omitted too much information. You have given the weight of the trolley but not the weight of the pieces to be lifted, their shapes (interlocked or not) and the types of metal to be separated (ferrous, non-ferrous, stainless steel, etc.).

Magnetic sorting of steel from non-ferrous metals will work provided they are not mechanically interlocked.

Sorting low-carbon steel from other steels will not work.

Regarding stainless-steel, the [British Stainless Steel Association](https://www.bssa.org.uk/faq.php?id=24) says,

> It is commonly stated that “stainless steel is non-magnetic”. This is not strictly true and the real situation is rather more complicated. The degree of magnetic response or magnetic permeability is derived from the microstructure of the steel. A totally non-magnetic material has a relative magnetic permeability of 1. Austenitic structures are totally non-magnetic and so a 100% austenitic stainless steel would have a permeability of 1. In practice this is not achieved. There is always a small amount of ferrite and/or martensite in the steel and so permeability values are always above 1. Typical values for standard austenitic stainless steels can be in the order of 1.05 – 1.1. See Composition effects on the magnetic permeability of austenitic stainless steels.
>
> It is possible for the magnetic permeability of austenitic steels to be changed during processing. For example, cold work and welding are liable to increase the amount of martensite and ferrite respectively in the steel. A familiar example is in a stainless steel sink where the flat drainer has little magnetic response whereas the pressed bowl has a higher response due to the formation of martensite particularly in the corners.
>
> In practical terms, austenitic stainless steels are used for “non-magnetic” applications, for example magnetic resonance imaging (MRI). In these cases, it is often necessary to agree a maximum magnetic permeability between customer and supplier. It can be as low as 1.004.
>
> Martensitic, ferritic, duplex and precipitation hardening steels are magnetic.